# How to retrieve user name from CAS in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, wicket, cas

I am working on a research project for a university, and I must build a portal-like web application where they see analysis information about their academic performances.

My web application is built using the Apache Wicket framework.

I need to use the university's CAS authentication server and use its login page to validate the user credentials. However, I also want to retrieve the name the user entered as username, as I need it for storage in session variables and use for the duration of the session.

I saw that CAS has a client for Apache Wicket, but I can't see how I can retrieve the username.

Any help would be appreciated,
Jeremie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for the client here https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Apache+Wicket+CAS+Client it looks like the getUser() method in CasAuthenticatedWebPage may be what you want.

```
/**
 * @return the authenticated principal name
 */
 public String getUser() {
 Session session = getSession();
 Serializable value = session.getAttribute(SSO_USER_NAME);
 return value + BLANK_STRING;
 }
```